# Is there any difference between cross entropy loss and logistic loss?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, loss-function

I want to use a logistic loss cost function for my deep learning model to solve a binary classification problem. I am using keras to build the model. However, keras doesn't have any pre-defined logistic [loss function](https://keras.io/losses/).

While reading about loss functions I came across confusing statements about cross entropy loss and logistic loss.
In this wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_functions_for_classification), there is a separate section for logistic loss and cross entropy loss.

However in this wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy), its mentioned that:

> The logistic loss is sometimes called cross-entropy loss.

Additionally, this sklearn [page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html) starts with:

> Log loss, aka logistic loss or cross-entropy loss.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The question might be more suitable for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

In keras use `binary_crossentropy` for classification problem with 2 class. use `categorical_crossentropy` for more than 2 classes.

Both are same only.If tensorflow is used as backend for keras then it uses below mentioned function to evaluate binary_crossentropy.

```
tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target,
                                                   logits=output)
```

**In documentation of this function below is mentions:**

For brevity, let x = logits, z = labels. The logistic loss is

```
z * -log(sigmoid(x)) + (1 - z) * -log(1 - sigmoid(x))
```